# Trying to get property 'title' of non-object Curl PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I have this Code which I am Using to Fetch Jobs From the Api:

```
        <?php

$header[] = "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  $header[] = "Accept:application/json";

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.adzuna.com/v1/api/jobs/gb/search/1?app_id=ID&app_key=KEY&results_per_page=20&what=PHP");

//do a POST
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,false);
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"id=333");


curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);




$result=json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);

//$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo "<pre>";


//print_r($result);

foreach ($result as $row){
   echo  $row->title;
}

?>
```

I am trying to access these values:

```
title
salary_max
description
redirect_url
salary_min
company
```

I am Getting these warnings :

> ```
>  Trying to get property 'title' of non-object in /www/wwwroot/demo.aekpani.net/recruit/wp-content/themes/recruit/Umair/api.php
> ```
>
> on line 31
>
> ```
>     Trying to get property 'title' of non-object in /www/wwwroot/demo.aekpani.net/recruit/wp-content/themes/recruit/Umair/api.php
> ```
>
> on line 31
>
> ```
>    Trying to get property 'title' of non-object in /www/wwwroot/demo.aekpani.net/recruit/wp-content/themes/recruit/Umair/api.php
> ```
>
> on line 31
>
> ```
>  Trying to get property 'title' of non-object in /www/wwwroot/demo.aekpani.net/recruit/wp-content/themes/recruit/Umair/api.php
> ```
>
> on line 31

Where am I Doing wrong???

if I do var_dump($result);

then the output is this :

```
 object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(39) "Adzuna::API::Response::JobSearchResults"
  ["results"]=>
  array(20) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (15) {
      ["description"]=>
      string(436) "PHP Developer - PHP / Javascript / MVC FULLY REMOTE WORKING OFFERED / Must be elgible to work in the UK on a permanent basis Key Skills: PHP, Laravel or Symfony or YII2 ... , JavaScript , MVC Desirable: Redux, Firebase, Docker , Angular An exciting opportunity is on offer for a PHP Developer to work for an innovative and growing Fintech business. This is a fully ..."
      ["company"]=>
      object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(7) "Ardotec"
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(30) "Adzuna::API::Response::Company"
      }
      ["redirect_url"]=>
      string(152) "https://www.adzuna.co.uk/jobs/land/ad/2143941919?se=vsCnrf-n6xGcCmimJBSbdg&utm_medium=api&utm_source=f6e0907b&v=07CB17CA90C1D1FC9E83060222D3D3C904E39638"
      ["created"]=>
      string(20) "2021-04-27T06:43:41Z"
      ["__CLASS__"]=>
      string(26) "Adzuna::API::Response::Job"
      ["salary_is_predicted"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["longitude"]=>
      float(-0.02806)
      ["salary_min"]=>
      int(45000)
      ["category"]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(31) "Adzuna::API::Response::Category"
        ["tag"]=>
        string(7) "it-jobs"
        ["label"]=>
        string(7) "IT Jobs"
      }
      ["latitude"]=>
      float(51.451818)
      ["title"]=>
      string(74) "PHP Developer - REMOTE / PHP /Javascript"
      ["id"]=>
      string(10) "2143941919"
      ["location"]=>
      object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(31) "Adzuna::API::Response::Location"
        ["area"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "UK"
          [1]=>
          string(6) "London"
          [2]=>
          string(17) "South East London"
        }
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(25) "South East London, London"
      }
      ["salary_max"]=>
      int(65000)
      ["adref"]=>
      string(128) "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoidnNDbnJmLW42eEdjQ21pbUpCU2JkZyIsImkiOiIyMTQzOTQxOTE5In0.YAVVLkLQi_SLQpFN89qyKiJZO-A03xvIJ4Nsfp7LOcg"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (15) {
      ["__CLASS__"]=>
      string(26) "Adzuna::API::Response::Job"
      ["created"]=>
      string(20) "2021-04-20T22:25:33Z"
      ["salary_is_predicted"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["redirect_url"]=>
      string(152) "https://www.adzuna.co.uk/jobs/land/ad/2129749481?se=vsCnrf-n6xGcCmimJBSbdg&utm_medium=api&utm_source=f6e0907b&v=F174AADA1D7F4CEC4AEA259B9DA762A7AE80BF97"
      ["salary_min"]=>
      int(30000)
      ["longitude"]=>
      float(0.523168)
      ["company"]=>
      object(stdClass)#7 (2) {
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(30) "Adzuna::API::Response::Company"
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(12) "White Stores"
      }
      ["description"]=>
      string(406) "PHP Developer Wickford, Essex £30,000 - £35,000 per annum (depending on experience) At White Stores we are passionate about outdoor living. For more than 15 years, we have ... . As we continue to grow and experience success after success, we are now seeking a PHP Developer to join us and play a vital role in the development of PHP web applications ..."
      ["location"]=>
      object(stdClass)#8 (3) {
        ["area"]=>
        array(4) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "UK"
          [1]=>
          string(15) "Eastern England"
          [2]=>
          string(5) "Essex"
          [3]=>
          string(8) "Wickford"
        }
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(31) "Adzuna::API::Response::Location"
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(15) "Wickford, Essex"
      }
      ["id"]=>
      string(10) "2129749481"
      ["adref"]=>
      string(128) "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMjEyOTc0OTQ4MSIsInMiOiJ2c0NucmYtbjZ4R2NDbWltSkJTYmRnIn0.QIdaNUTbRquI_T0_C2rAgfr-jOYABSU-bkq8m-DrPSM"
      ["salary_max"]=>
      int(35000)
      ["category"]=>
      object(stdClass)#9 (3) {
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(31) "Adzuna::API::Response::Category"
        ["tag"]=>
        string(7) "it-jobs"
        ["label"]=>
        string(7) "IT Jobs"
      }
      ["latitude"]=>
      float(51.6106)
      ["title"]=>
      string(30) "PHP Developer"
    }
```

this is the result above I posted some of it as i am not able to post fully results here ...

if I do this:

```
$result=json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);

//$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo "<pre>";


var_dump($result);
```

the output is like this ...

```
array(4) {   ["mean"]=>   float(45274.4)   ["count"]=>   int(6140)   ["__CLASS__"]=>   string(39) "Adzuna::API::Response::JobSearchResults" ["results"]=>   array(20) {
    [0]=>
    array(15) {
      ["salary_min"]=>
      int(45000)
      ["location"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["area"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "UK"
          [1]=>
          string(6) "London"
          [2]=>
          string(17) "South East London"
        }
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(25) "South East London, London"
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(31) "Adzuna::API::Response::Location"
      }
      ["salary_max"]=>
      int(65000)
      ["description"]=>
      string(436) "PHP Developer - PHP / Javascript / MVC FULLY REMOTE WORKING OFFERED / Must be elgible to work in the UK on a permanent basis Key Skills: PHP, Laravel or Symfony or YII2 ... , JavaScript , MVC Desirable: Redux, Firebase, Docker , Angular An exciting opportunity is on offer for a PHP Developer to work for an innovative and growing Fintech business. This is a fully ..."
      ["__CLASS__"]=>
      string(26) "Adzuna::API::Response::Job"
      ["longitude"]=>
      float(-0.02806)
      ["title"]=>
      string(74) "PHP Developer - REMOTE / PHP /Javascript"
      ["adref"]=>
      string(128) "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoiSktOWEJBYW82eEdXVTd0VzN0MlRWQSIsImkiOiIyMTQzOTQxOTE5In0.xdtRRI8U0hAlL3q9NvVfXP8yZ_EWoB7o3ZUbN4856u0"
      ["category"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(7) "IT Jobs"
        ["tag"]=>
        string(7) "it-jobs"
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(31) "Adzuna::API::Response::Category"
      }
      ["redirect_url"]=>
      string(152) "https://www.adzuna.co.uk/jobs/land/ad/2143941919?se=JKNXBAao6xGWU7tW3t2TVA&utm_medium=api&utm_source=f6e0907b&v=07CB17CA90C1D1FC9E83060222D3D3C904E39638"
      ["created"]=>
      string(20) "2021-04-27T06:43:41Z"
      ["latitude"]=>
      float(51.451818)
      ["id"]=>
      string(10) "2143941919"
      ["salary_is_predicted"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["company"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(7) "Ardotec"
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(30) "Adzuna::API::Response::Company"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(15) {
      ["salary_is_predicted"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["company"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(12) "White Stores"
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(30) "Adzuna::API::Response::Company"
      }
      ["id"]=>
      string(10) "2129749481"
      ["latitude"]=>
      float(51.6106)
      ["created"]=>
      string(20) "2021-04-20T22:25:33Z"
      ["redirect_url"]=>
      string(152) "https://www.adzuna.co.uk/jobs/land/ad/2129749481?se=JKNXBAao6xGWU7tW3t2TVA&utm_medium=api&utm_source=f6e0907b&v=F174AADA1D7F4CEC4AEA259B9DA762A7AE80BF97"
      ["category"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["tag"]=>
        string(7) "it-jobs"
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(31) "Adzuna::API::Response::Category"
        ["label"]=>
        string(7) "IT Jobs"
      }
      ["adref"]=>
      string(128) "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMjEyOTc0OTQ4MSIsInMiOiJKS05YQkFhbzZ4R1dVN3RXM3QyVFZBIn0.LbCbnV_bIM1qvNR1Dy3QDrpk7GbrSimhQ9PBXKlYdHQ"
      ["title"]=>
      string(30) "PHP Developer"
      ["longitude"]=>
      float(0.523168)
      ["description"]=>
      string(406) "PHP Developer Wickford, Essex £30,000 - £35,000 per annum (depending on experience) At White Stores we are passionate about outdoor living. For more than 15 years, we have ... . As we continue to grow and experience success after success, we are now seeking a PHP Developer to join us and play a vital role in the development of PHP web applications ..."
      ["__CLASS__"]=>
      string(26) "Adzuna::API::Response::Job"
      ["salary_max"]=>
      int(35000)
      ["location"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(15) "Wickford, Essex"
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(31) "Adzuna::API::Response::Location"
        ["area"]=>
        array(4) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "UK"
          [1]=>
          string(15) "Eastern England"
          [2]=>
          string(5) "Essex"
          [3]=>
          string(8) "Wickford"
        }
      }
      ["salary_min"]=>
      int(30000)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(15) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(30) "PHP developer"
      ["longitude"]=>
      float(-2.29854)
      ["description"]=>
      string(419) "PHP developer - Manchester - £32,000 A PHP developer is required to join a well-established, innovative and award-winning business based in north Manchester as they expand ...  the development team. Having serviced businesses from small corner shops, to blue chip organisations across the UK, the successful PHP developer will have the opportunity to work on some ..."
      ["__CLASS__"]=>
      string(26) "Adzuna::API::Response::Job"
      ["salary_max"]=>
      int(32000)
      ["location"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(24) "Bury, Greater Manchester"
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(31) "Adzuna::API::Response::Location"
        ["area"]=>
        array(4) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "UK"
          [1]=>
          string(18) "North West England"
          [2]=>
          string(18) "Greater Manchester"
          [3]=>
          string(4) "Bury"
        }
      }
      ["salary_min"]=>
      int(28000)
      ["salary_is_predicted"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["company"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(6) "Capita"
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(30) "Adzuna::API::Response::Company"
      }
      ["id"]=>
      string(10) "2102200703"
      ["latitude"]=>
      float(53.593498)
      ["redirect_url"]=>
      string(152) "https://www.adzuna.co.uk/jobs/land/ad/2102200703?se=JKNXBAao6xGWU7tW3t2TVA&utm_medium=api&utm_source=f6e0907b&v=395C49C57A5FC0605CD718A9D5FDF04E985F3780"
      ["created"]=>
      string(20) "2021-04-06T18:58:11Z"
      ["category"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(7) "IT Jobs"
        ["tag"]=>
        string(7) "it-jobs"
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(31) "Adzuna::API::Response::Category"
      }
      ["adref"]=>
      string(128) "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMjEwMjIwMDcwMyIsInMiOiJKS05YQkFhbzZ4R1dVN3RXM3QyVFZBIn0.OGD0UUmtvmcN-BDauzaIIpEzqg2TwPOWmIen6AldiG0"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(13) {
      ["location"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(31) "Adzuna::API::Response::Location"
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(2) "UK"
        ["area"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "UK"
        }
      }
      ["salary_min"]=>
      int(0)
      ["description"]=>
      string(408) "Mid / Senior PHP Developer technologi are looking for a capable, knowledgeable, motivated individual to assist in developing the software that supports the service proposition ...  revolution to the UK card payments industry focusing on system innovation and service excellence. Salary: Up to £65,000 Job Type: Full Time Responsibilities of the Mid/Senior PHP Developer ..."
      ["__CLASS__"]=>
      string(26) "Adzuna::API::Response::Job"
      ["salary_max"]=>
      int(65000)
      ["title"]=>
      string(30) "PHP Developer"
      ["category"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(7) "IT Jobs"
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(31) "Adzuna::API::Response::Category"
        ["tag"]=>
        string(7) "it-jobs"
      }
      ["adref"]=>
      string(128) "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoiSktOWEJBYW82eEdXVTd0VzN0MlRWQSIsImkiOiIyMDkxNDMwNDMwIn0.zhUM-Aw2XdL-gVddZ6279px_pj3gs6ZWr_WKXpfkoX8"
      ["redirect_url"]=>
      string(152) "https://www.adzuna.co.uk/jobs/land/ad/2091430430?se=JKNXBAao6xGWU7tW3t2TVA&utm_medium=api&utm_source=f6e0907b&v=2720D4577AE58EBCB28D1478075CC47866B3CF33"
      ["created"]=>
      string(20) "2021-04-01T18:21:44Z"
      ["id"]=>
      string(10) "2091430430"
      ["company"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(10) "technologi"
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(30) "Adzuna::API::Response::Company"
      }
      ["salary_is_predicted"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
```

Thanks In Advance..

Comment: The error is clear - you're trying to perform property access on something that is not an object (it's an array, as your second dump is showing). So either decode as object (without the second `true` parameter in `json_decode`) or use array access.

Comment: @El_Vanja but even if I access it like this $result['title']; it says undefined index .?

Comment: and if I put that property to false and then try using this
$result->title; it still gives error

Comment: That's because `title` isn't an index at the top level of the array. Look at your dump, it shows you the whole array structure.

Comment: @El_Vanja  so how am I able to access title ? sorry i am newbie.

Comment: If you have no idea how arrays work, then you should start by reading the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) about them.

Comment: You need to iterate over `$results` array key `results`

Comment: @DamianDziaduch thanks . got it so it becomes like this 

$result=json_decode(curl_exec($ch),false);

foreach ($result->results as $job){
echo $job->id;
}

and when the json parameter is true ..


foreach ($result['results'] as $job){
echo $job['id'];
} 

then this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it becomes like this

```
$result=json_decode(curl_exec($ch),false); 

foreach ($result->results as $job){ 
echo $job->id; 
}
```

and when the json parameter is true i.e ..

then this :

```
$result=json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);  

foreach ($result['results'] as $job){ 

echo $job['id']; 

}
```